# java.lang.NumberFormatException in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a list of user groups which I want to display in JSF page:

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{AddAccountController.formMap['GROUPID']}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{AddAccountController.usergroups.groupid}" itemValue="#{AddAccountController.usergroups.groupname}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This is the managed bean code which generates the list:

```
private List<listGroupsObj> usergroups = new ArrayList<>();
......
public void initListGroups() throws SQLException {

        if (ds == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }
        /* Initialize a connection to Oracle */
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }
        /* With SQL statement get all settings and values */
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from USERGROUPS");

        try {
            //get data from database        
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                /* Put the the data from Oracle into Hash Map */                
                usergroups.add(new listGroupsObj(result.getInt("GROUPID"), result.getString("GROUPNAME")));

            }
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    } 

    public class listGroupsObj {
        private int groupid;
        private String groupname;

        public listGroupsObj(int groupid, String groupname){
            this.groupid = groupid;
            this.groupname = groupname;           
        }

        public int getGroupid()
        {
            return groupid;
        }   

        public void setGroupid(int groupid)
        {
            this.groupid = groupid;
        }

        public String getGroupname()
        {
            return groupname;
        }

        public void setGroupname(String groupname)
        {
            this.groupname = groupname;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return groupname;
        }
    }

    // Get the list with User Groups
    public List<listGroupsObj> getusergroups() {       
        return usergroups;
    }
```

When I open the JSF page I get this error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "groupid"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
```

It seems that I cannot display integer into the select menu.
How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `<f:selectItems>` tag, the `value` attribute must represent the list of all available items. The `itemValue` (and `itemLabel`) attributes can only be used when the `var` attribute is specified, which represents each individual item of the list.

Your particular problem is caused because you used

```html
<f:selectItems value="#{AddAccountController.usergroups.groupid}" />
```

which is syntactically invalid. The `#{AddAccountController.usergroups}` returns a `List` which can only be accessed further by an integer index like so `#{AddAccountController.usergroups[0]}` for the 1st item. But you tried to use `groupid` which isn't a valid index value as it's not an `Integer`. But you shouldn't be accessing it this way.

This is the proper usage:

```html
<f:selectItems value="#{AddAccountController.usergroups}" var="usergroup"
    itemValue="#{usergroup.groupid}" itemLabel="#{usergroup.groupname}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Our `h:selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Answer (score 1):

It tries to bind `groupId` with `int` `groupId` field of bean and that is invalid